# Difference between using a sampler and direct indexed access

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl, compute-shader

If I have a texture input in my compute shader, is there any significant difference between using the index operator [] or using a sampler, apart from interpolation and using indexes vs normalized coordinates? If I don't need to interpolate, is there a significant performance loss when using a sampler?

```
RWTexture3D<float4> Output;
Texture3D<float4> Input;
SamplerState samplerInput;

[numthreads(8, 8, 8)]
void main(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float width, height, depth;
    Output.GetDimensions(width, height, depth);
    float3 dimensions = float3(width, height, depth);
    float3 coords = id.xyz / dimensions;
    float4 value;

    // Sampler:
    value = Input.SampleLevel(samplerInput, coords, 0);

    // Index operator:
    value = Input[id];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The sampler is a very heavily-optimized bit of hardware on the video card, so using it or not isn't likely to dominate your performance. The memory access pattern matters more, and with a sampler with mipmapping it's likely to be more efficient than direct indexing of the 'top mip'. But as with everything about optimization, your best bet is to actually profile it.